# What's wrong in my code ? in continuous count in JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am trying to achieve 3,4,5 in output. But, am getting only 3,5 .its jumping/skipping one number. Donno why. Given my code below. Help me to fix the error and please let me know why its happening and what i am doing as error ?

**Expected output,**

```
3
4
5
```

**output am getting,**

```
3
5
```

**my code,**

```
var input1, input2;
input1 = Number(2);
input2 = Number(5);
for(let i=input1;i<input2;i++) {
    i=i+1;
    console.log(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop already increments `i` for you. The loop you wrote executes in the following path, going from 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> 3 and repeats unless the check at 3 is false:

```
for(
let i=input1; // 1. Declare initial value [i]
i<input2;     // 3. Check if [i] < [input2]
i++           // 4. increment [i] by 1
) 
{             
  i=i+1;      // 2. Run the contents of the loop body
  console.log(i);
}
```

That means

```
// First iteration
i = input1        // 1. i = Number(2);
  i = i + 1;      // 2. i = 2 + 1;
  console.log(i)  // 2. console.log(3);
i < input2 ?      // 3. Check if i is smaller than input2. End loop if not
i++;              // 4. Increment i so i = 4

// Second iteration
  i = i + 1;      // 2. i = 4 + 1;
  console.log(i)  // 2. console.log(5);
i < input2 ?      // 3. Check if i is smaller than input2. End loop if not

// End loop since i < input2 is not true
```

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing `i` inside the body of the `for` loop even though it already does it for you.

`input1` should also be `3`.

Use:

```js
var input1, input2;
input1 = Number(3);
input2 = Number(5);
for (let i = input1; i <= input2; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fastest reply it works after removing i=i+1;

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing variable 'i' two times

1. On for loop

   ```
    for(let i=input1;i<input2;i++) {}
   ```
2. Inside for loop

   ```
     i=i+1;
   ```

So your variable 'i' will increment with 2